# sqlite trigger after update syntax error

Tags: sqlite, triggers

How ever I try to modify my trigger syntax, this error keeps getting up all the time, error near "ROWID" or "PERSONID". I just cant figure out what is wrong.

```
/* PERSON */

CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PERSONID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    MODERATOR BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    SCORE INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CREATEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATETIME('now')),
    MODIFYDATE DATETIME,

    PRIMARY KEY (PERSONID)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trg_personupdate AFTER UPDATE ON PERSON
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PERSON
            SET MODIFYDATE = DATETIME('NOW')
            WHERE ROWID = new.ROWID;
    END;
```

sqlite outputs:

```
 13:51:28  [/* - 0 row(s), 0.026 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
 13:51:28  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.040 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
 13:51:28  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1]  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "ROWID": syntax error)
 13:51:28  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1]  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (cannot commit - no transaction is active)
... 4 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.066/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 2 warnings, 2 errors]
```

I suppose "WHERE PERSONID = NEW.PERSONID" - should also work, but then the error just changes to error near "PERSONID"

Comment: This exact code works for me.

Comment: tip: remove sqlite to avoid confusing it to sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

The database was initialized using sqlite, not sqlite3. So somehow some features worked well, while trigger didn't.

Creating new database with **sqlite3** fixed the issue.